# Passing multiple argument to dbGetQuery()?

Tags: sql, r, oracle, roracle

I am using ROracle package to fetch records from database. I need to pass multiple values from `dbGetQuery()`, so that I can use them in where clause of query.
Suppose I have:

```
 query <- "select abc from tablename where value1= (:1)
```

Then I can get the table data by calling

```
data <- dbGetQuery(connection, query, condition1 ).
```

I will get the data in data variable. 
The problem I am facing is if I have to pass multiple values from `dbGetQuery()`
then how to do it.

Example:

```
query <- "select abc from tablename where value1= (:1) and value1=(:2)
```

now if I call

```
data <- dbGetQuery(connection, query, condition1, condition2)
```

it will give error.

I tried passing a vector but still i am getting error, like

```
data <- dbGetQuery(connection, query, c("condition1", "condition2"))
```

Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
data <- dbGetQuery(connection, query, 
                   list=as.list(c("condition1", "condition2")))
```

Hope it helps.